# Is my IQueryable syntax correct?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, subsonic, subsonic3

The generated SQL does a cross join but as the ID's are matched it acts like an inner join but is there a better performing way to do this by actually using the join keyword in C#? Is there a way where you don't have to specify how the properties join because they are all heirarchicly related anyway

Item is a Page class

PageRoles is an IQueryable property in a Page class

aspnet_Roles is an IQueryable property in a PageRole class

```
var item = _repository.GetByKey(999);

var f = (from fd in item.PageRoles 
         from k in fd.aspnet_Roles 
         where Roles.GetRolesForUser().Contains(k.RoleName) 
         && k.RoleId == fd.RoleId 
         select k.RoleName)
        .Count();
```

**EDIT:**

Here is an example of an IQueryable property in my classes. The below example comes from the PageRole class

```
public IQueryable<aspnet_Role> aspnet_Roles
{
    get
    {

          var repo=NorthCadburyWebsite.Models.aspnet_Role.GetRepo();
          return from items in repo.GetAll()
               where items.RoleId == _RoleId
               select items;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have my Intellisense with me but I think you can:

```
var f = (from fd in item.PageRoles 
         join k in fd.aspnet_Roles on k.RoleId equals fd.RoleId
         where Roles.GetRolesForUser().Contains(k.RoleName) 
         select k.RoleName)
        .Count();
```

Comment: Change the == to equals, and you'll have to swap so fd.RoleId is on the left and k.RoleId is on the right, but yes I believe this is correct. I'm still trying to get my head around the purpose of the join and the hierarchy tho...

Comment: you can't do join k in fd.aspnet_Roles because for some reason it doesn't recognise fd...?

Comment: I think I was right the first time... The K.RoleID goes first before the equals.

Answer (score 0):

Does this compile or do you get an error?

In this case, as you mentioned, you don't need a join.
I haven't used this syntax, but it looks like you use k as a refererence (like an alias in sql syntax)

This should deliver the same result (without even using k):

```
var f = (from fd in item.PageRoles 
         where Roles.GetRolesForUser().Contains(fd.aspnet_Roles.RoleName) 
         && fd.aspnet_Roles.RoleId == fd.RoleId 
         select fd.aspnet_Roles.RoleName)
        .Count();
```

Note: Not tested, just a guess.

Comment: Can't do fd.aspnet_Roles.RoleName as fd.aspnet_Roles is IQueryable and not an instance of the class

Answer (score -1):

I think I'm confused, because I'm seeing the following hierarchy in your query which isn't making any sense:

```
[PageRoles]
|--RoleId <~~~~~~~~~.
|--[aspnet_Roles]   |
   |--RoleId ~~~~~~~*
   |--RoleName
```

---

Is the hierarchy determined by the `RoleId` and you only mean for `PageRoles.RoleId` to reference `aspnet_Roles.RoleId`? So you might have something like:

```
[PageRoles]  [aspnet_Roles]
|--RoleId    |--RoleId
             |--RoleName
```

And you're trying to make it into the following:

```
[PageRoles]
|--RoleId 
|--[aspnet_Roles] (where RoleId == PageRoles.RoleId)
   |--RoleName
```

...?

---

In which case if you can't do the following, then *something is wrong with your IQueryable property definitions* and not the query you have posted. Namely the method to get `PageRoles`'s `aspnet_Roles` child rows is not set up properly.

```
var f = (from fd in item.PageRoles 
         from k in fd.aspnet_Roles 
         where Roles.GetRolesForUser().Contains(k.RoleName) 
         select k.RoleName)
        .Count();
```

(`fd.aspnet_Roles` should already be constrained by `RoleId` and generate an inner join).

You can check your hierarchy by seeing what SQL is generated from:

```
var f = from fd in item.PageRoles
        from k in fd.aspnet_Roles
        select k;
```

which should vaguely resemble (with something having to do with item thrown in):

```
SELECT k.RoleName, k.SomethingElse
FROM PageRoles fd
INNER JOIN aspnetRoles k ON fd.RoleId = k.RoleId;
```

---

I'm sure I'm missing something, so please help me fill in the blanks...